# Determine the Impedance of piezo using NanoVNA

Tags: piezo

What is the right tool to verify the resonant frequency of 1 Mhz (per spec) piezo?  Consider that I need something low cost, does it make sense to use NanoVNA or does it require an impedance analyzer?

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest a function generator and oscilloscope, couple to the resonator and see when the voltage is maximized / minimized, but Murata describe it much better:

[image]

from:
https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/43406.pdf